# Using jar from scala project from python via Py4j

Tags: java, python, scala, jar, py4j

I have built a jar from my Scala project.

I have the following structure for what I want to use from this jar

```
package aaa.bbb.ccc    

case class FooResult(...)

trait Foo(...) {
  def bar(): FooResult
}

object Foo {
  private class FooImpl(...) extends Foo {
    ...
  }

  def apply(...): Foo
}
```

First question: Maybe I have misunderstood something in what Py4J offers, 
but do I have to write a java/scala class to start the Py4J gateway if I want to use my own classes? Or is it enough to add it to the gateway's jvm's classpath?

Second question (which I guess doesn't apply depending on the answer to above): How do I add my jar when starting the java gateway in order to make it available? To solve this temporarily, I just started the jvm manually with my jar along with the Py4J jar with this command

```
java -classpath "path/to/py4j.jar:path/to/my.jar" py4j.GatewayServer 0
```

and then connected to it manually from the Python code. Then I tried to import my classes via

```
java_import(gateway.jvm, "aaa.bbb.ccc.*")
```

which didn't throw any error but I'm not sure it worked because it doesn't throw any error if I input some fake classpath.

Third question (which applies if the answer to the first is that I have to write the entry point to access my classes): How does this work when using scala?

```
object Main extends App {
  val gw = new GatewayServer(// TODO: how to expose my classes here?
}
```

Comment: 1. Starting a GatewayServer with your custom jar in the classpath is enough.
2. java_import just adds a lookup path, it does not execute anything. Try calling a real method, such as gateway.jvm.System.out.println("Hello World")
3. I don't know Scala enough to be able to answer but you may be interested in https://pypi.python.org/pypi/spylon/

Comment: Thanks, I think the issues came from how to access stuff defined in scala from the java side so to speak. It was easier to just write the things I wanted to expose to python as methods in the Main object and pass that as the entry point which then just worked as expected.